# will an IPA file overwrite one I already have installed on iPad

Tags: ios, ipa

I have an existing app on my iPad from an iPad file, if I upload another ipa file (different name) will it erase the ipa file/app on the iPad and replace it with the new one ???

Comment: as long as they have different bundle identifier, it won't

Answer (score 0):

If the bundle id is same, then ipa with different name will replace the build in the ipad.But if the bundle id is different, then builds will not be replaced.